# xlPasteValues and xlPasteFormats at the same time

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, paste

I am copying a range and then pasting its values and formats to another range:

```vb
ws5.Range("F3:N" & xCell).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    
ws16.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(4, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ws16.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(4, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

Is it possible to do these two paste actions in one action without using `With`?

I would like to increase the speed of my macro and that kind of small reduction might help me.

Is there something like `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues and xlPasteFormats`?

I found [link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/167518-pastespecial-values-formats-same-time.html) but even this answer is using `With`, which is useless for me.

Comment: if you want to copy also the Cell's Background color, then you need to use the **2-Lines** syntax you are currently using

Comment: So there is no other way to pretend using second line. Something seems easy, but not possible  at the same time in this application:)

Comment: You can create your own function to do that. This way, you won't need to write two lines of code every time (if that's the problem)

Comment: To answer your question, No there is no way to paste values and formats all in one command, the closest you can get is values and number formats but not cell formats. Can I ask why it's such an issue to do values then formats? Also why are you against using a with statement? It's clean and efficient. If you are that against with I supposed you could set up a range variable called `PasteRange` and use `PasteRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValue: PasteRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats` but it would be very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way:

```
NewSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
NewSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Place the two commands one after each other. First, you have to paste all, then you paste again, but only values and number formats.

Answer (score -1):

`xlPasteAll`

(Actually, since `xlPasteAll` is the default paste option, you can just leave it off.)

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195818(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however xlPasteAll pastes formulas not values.

Comment: @Mertinc No, it pastes everything.  The documentation explains what each constant means: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlpastetype.aspx

Comment: Oh, yes but I don't want formulas to be pasted , when you paste everything it pastes the formulas as well. I simply want to only paste it's values.

Comment: @Mertinc Oh ok, I didn't understand realize that.

Comment: No worries at all mate. Thanks for your effort anyway. I think it's not possible to combine paste values with format at the same time.

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for:

```
xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

### edit## This is not the correct answer.

Comment: `xlPasteFormats` is doing exactly same thing with **Format Painter** is this `NumberFormats` does the same?

Comment: Erm, I guess I misread the question. The answer really is that you cannot combine those two, you have to do two paste specials.

Comment: If this is not the correct answer, you should simply delete it rather than editing to say it's not correct.

Answer (score -3):

You can paste the content several times to get what you need, like

```
Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```